# Mouse select in tmux adds concatenation of everything ever selected to clipboard

Tags: copy-paste, tmux

I have `set -g mouse on` in my .tmux.conf – and only this (I removed everything else from it to try an locate the issue).

When I select something with the mouse, sometimes it stays selected and I can copy it normally, but more often, the selection disappears as soon as I release the mouse button. When this happens I end up having everything I ever had in my clipboard concatenated to one large string in my clipboard.
I cleared all three selections with xsel before, but still after this things I had in my clipboard hours ago, even before I started the current tmux server reappear in the clipboard.

What is causing this, is this intended behavior and how can I stop it?
Where are my previous selections saved and by whom?

What I did to narrow it down:

- `mv .tmux.conf .tmux.conf.bk; echo "set -g mouse on" > .tmux.conf`
- `mv .tmux .tmux.bk`
- `xsel -c -p`
- `xsel -c -s`
- `xsel -c -b`
- `tmux kill-server`
- made sure there is not /etc/tmux.conf
- run as different user, without any bashrc

It still occurs.

Comment: I ran into the issue you describe, but on Mac instead of Linux. It turned out my issue was that the terminal emulator I'm using (Kitty) defaults to appending all clipboard writes instead of just taking the last one. I had to explicitly set it to `no-append` per this github issue (https://github.com/kovidgoyal/kitty/issues/782#issuecomment-502927322). Is it possible that your issue is also a terminal emulator issue instead of a tmux one?